# How to invoke Nodejs lambda from Java based Lambda in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I was trying to invoke Nodejs based lambda from Java-Based lambda. It is invoking the lambda but the payload is not being sent to Nodejs based lambda.
Here is the code for both lambdas:

Nodejs based lambda:

```
module.exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('event ', event) // Payload not coming here either event or context
    console.log('context', context)
    const body = JSON.parse(event);
   //Processing and return response
}
```

Java-based lambda:

```
AWSLambda client = AWSLambdaClient.builder().withRegion(region).build();
InvokeRequest().withFunctionName("nodejslambda").withPayload(payload);
InvokeResult result = client.invoke(req);
```

Your help would be greatly appricated.

Comment: The nodejs lambda has been called or not?

Comment: nodejs lambda has called but payload not coming there which is sending from java lambda

Comment: Show your payload. Just try with new payload like `.withPayload("123456");`

Comment: My payload is: 
`{
    "profile": {
        "key": "value"
    }
}`

Comment: However, I tried with `.withPayload("123456")` still the payload not displaying in nodejs lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide additional information like

1. Are you able to see the node function invoked and what is the response body when you call the invoke method.
2. Check the node lambda logs if you see the function invoked.
3. Try to test the function on the console by sending the same payload as test.

Comment: For #2 and #3, The node lambda was invoking verified in cloudwatch logs. From the console, the node lambda is working fine.
For #1, Yes node function invoked and returning error due to payload not being sent.

Comment: Can you please add the stack-trace being returned